# App crashes while setting text in textView

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

XML Code

```
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="192dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:id="@+id/nav_header">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>
```

***java Code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    btn2 = findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.user_Name);
    textView.setText("My text");
}
```

App crashes when i use this code to set Text, getting null pointer exception

Comment: Please post a complete example, including the xml and the error message you are getting. This could be caused by calling this before the ```setContentView``` method is called in ```onCreate```, or if ```user_Name``` is not a valid view id.

Comment: More information  needed. Please provide an error message as well as inside which function did you place this code.

Comment: Please post the logcat content ....

Comment: k but why i am getting this error , also check i have modified my code

Comment: @Techwithsrt is the user_Name TexView inside activity_home.xml file ?

Comment: yes sir it is the id of my Textview

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.insert_update_delete/com.example.insert_update_delete.Home}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference      This error i am getting

Comment: @DmitriiLeonov sir please help, from two days i am trying to get this done but i m failing

Comment: What you have posted looks correct, are you sure this is an exact copy of what's failing in your code? The error you are getting means it can't find the `TextView` referred to by `R.id.user_Name` so it returns null. Try to post a complete activity and xml file that replicates the error so someone else could try it.

Comment: can you post complete code of your activity

Comment: Done the same please check

Comment: Can you edit the code into your question rather than posting it as comments. Comments don't support formatting and can be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

you can't access **navigation drawer header** directly.

do this:

```
 NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.your_navigation_drawer_id);
 View navHeaderView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

 TextView textView = navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.user_Name);
 textView.setText("My text");
```

Comment: @Techwithsrt yes on `onCreate()`